# Crossfade between dynamically assigned background images without white flash

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Project link.](http://regalia.thesolutionisverysimple.com/)

If you go to the "Residences" option from the top navigation, and then click on any item in the left submenu item (Bathroom, Kitchen etc). The main div, in which the content for Residences is arriving, the background image will change.

JS:

```
$('.resMenu li a').click(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('bckimg');
$('.resMenu li a').removeClass('clicked');
$(this).addClass('clicked');
var num = $(this).attr('rel');
var image = $('#section-2');
image.fadeOut(500, function () {
    image.css({
        'background':'url('+href+') center top no-repeat',
        'background-size':'cover'
    });
    image.fadeIn(500);
});
});
```

JS for preloading images:

```
// Array of images:
var imageArray = [
'<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/resi-1.jpg', 
'<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/resi-2.jpg', 
'<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/resi-3.jpg'
                ];

// Loop through and declare an element that will not actually be used.
$.each(imageArray, function (i, val) {
  $('#alwaysHide').append('<img src="'+ val +'">')
});
```

What this does is, that it makes the page white (the fade effect isn't working either), while the transition is happening. I looked at the previously asked questions related to this but they always either had an  tag or the css was predefined, which is not possible for me to do here. Any ideas how the white flash can be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

It goes white because that is the background color. The images need to be loaded. This is why it shows the background, because there is no image there before it has loaded.

You will need to preload your images using Javascript if you want to avoid this.

The browser loads the image the first time, but the second time it has been cached which is why it only shows the white the first time you visit that section.

Comment: The images are being preloaded, please check the edit in the question now.

Comment: `$('<img/>').attr('src', val);` This isn't preloading the image. It needs to be added to the DOM to be loaded by the browser.

Comment: I added a div, positioned it away from the visible area and called all the images inside of it, and yet, when the side navigation item is clicked, the browser downloads the images once again. Check the edit for browser cache.